# Get data from table and save to database

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am trying to get the data from all rows and save it to database. how to get data from table.

Thanks for any help.

This is my javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this).next().hide();
        });
    });

function add_row(){
    var order_table = document.getElementById('order_list');
    var food_name = document.getElementById('food0')
    var food_quantity = document.getElementById('quantity')
    // Insert new row

    var new_row = order_table.insertRow(0);
    var nee_cell0 = new_row.insertCell(0);
    var nee_cell1 = new_row.insertCell(1);
    var nee_cell2 = new_row.insertCell(2);
    var nee_cell3 = new_row.insertCell(3);
    var nee_cell4 = new_row.insertCell(4);
    nee_cell0.innerHTML = "{{ forloop.counter }}";
    nee_cell1.innerHTML = food_name.value;
    nee_cell2.innerHTML = food_quantity.value;
    nee_cell3.innerHTML = 'safakat';
    nee_cell4.innerHTML = 'safakat';
}
```

This is my Html file.

```
<body>
<input list="food_item" name="food0" id="food0" placeholder="Search for food item"><br>
<input type="number" name="unit_price">
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" placeholder="Enter The Quantity"><br>
<button onclick="add_row()">ADD ROW</button>
<table align="center" name = 'table'>
    <tr>
        <th>Sl. No.</th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th name='abc'>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<table align="center" id="order_list">
</table>
<datalist id="food_item">
    {% for i in food %}
        <option value="{{i.name}}">
    {% endfor %}
    
</datalist>
</body>
```

I am trying request.POST.getlist('table_name'). but i am getting empty list

Comment: I don't understand, where is data being submitted? There is no form?

Comment: because i deleted it before posting it to make it short. I can not find any code to get data from html table.request.POST.getlist('table') returns empty list.

Comment: But you can't get data from HTML. The HTML is just in your browser, not sent to your server. What you submit to your django view is either: 1) when using <form> in your HTML, the form will submit all its enclosed <input> elements as key-value pairs. 2) when using ajax, whatever your ajax chooses to send as form-data (key-value pairs). The first method is the most straightforward, the second if you have a single-page application of more complex processing required on the client before submitting to your django server.

Comment: I know how to submit using <form> in html but how to retrive table data from html not database to html using python request?.

Comment: you can't. you have to submit the data in an HTTP request as form-data. That's how HTTP works. I mean, you could write javascript to submit the entire HTML of your table as a multipart/form-data attachment (like a file) and then parse this HTML, but seems like a lot of work to submit a list of values.

Comment: i know but what i want to know is what is the code to retrive the data from table.request.POST.getlist() or request.POST[] is not working.

Comment: there is no python code to retrieve the data from the table because the table never reaches python.

Comment: ok.Thanks for help.

Comment: I mean, you already have javascript to add rows to the table. Why not keep a local javascript object that keeps track of the values added and then submit that as form-data when the user submits your form.

Comment: Because i dont know javascript, ajax in very detail.

Comment: Alternatively, what you're trying to do is better solved with a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/). You'll still need javascript to add each form when the user wants to add a row (similar to what you do with the table) but when you submit the formset, you get a lot of functionality "for free". This would **replace** your table method. And no need for ajax.

Comment: ok.Let me check